# antiderivative of $\psi'(u)$ for $u\in W^{1,2}_0((a,b))$

Tags: integration, derivatives, sobolev-spaces

Let $u\in W^{1,2}_0((a,b))$ and $\psi'$ the derivative of a convex function $\Psi\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$. If I want to consider the antiderivative of $\psi'(u)$, what happens with the $u$ inside $\Psi(u)$? Is it possible to say how does the antiderivative looks like? I need this for an other proof.
Regards

Comment: Take $u(x) = -x^2$ and $\phi(x) = e^x$ , then $\phi'(u(x)) = e^{-x^2}$, and it's well known that an antiderivative of it cannot be expressed in finite terms of $u$ and $\phi$

Comment: Oh you are right, thanks!